# binding dataitem to columns in gridview

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, gridview

```
<%# ((DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["SomeProperty"] %>
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SomeProperty")%>
```

From Google i figured out these can be used to bind the columns in `GridView` to `ArrayList`. But what is "some property" ?

For example i have a `ArrayList` in .aspx.cs as

```
static ArrayList componentSelectionArray = new ArrayList();
```

so can i just write in grid view to bind a arraylist to grid view columns as:

```
<asp:GridView ID= "GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true">
  <Columns>    
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ComponentName">
      <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="" text= "<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "componentSelectionArray")%>" ></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</asp:GridView>
```

Please help me

Thank you in anticipation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To bind to an `ArrayList` you just have to get the the underlying `DataItem`.

Assuming your `ArrayList` is storing a `string` you just have to do:

```
<asp:Label ID="" Text="<%# GetDataItem().ToString() %>"></asp:Label>
```

`GetDataItem()`: Gets the data item at the top of the data-binding context stack.

More info on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.getdataitem.aspx).